# Pushing Notifications to iOS Devices with an HTTP Post other than a socket connection

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to send the APNs a push notification for clients without using the socket opening method? If I could just send the parameters with an HTTP Post that should be pretty easy, but I can't seem to find anything indicating this is possible.

I'm using Google AppEngine for my server, and I've been wrestling with opening up a socket (even had a different thread here for that) for a couple days now, and it seems useless.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, apple use a SSL connection, with certificates, to send Push message.
You might be able to use a third party API to push via HTTP.

Comment: Can you recommend such a service?

Comment: No, since I've never used one, but you might want to have look at [urban airship](http://urbanairship.com/)